# Finding prime factors in Prolog

Tags: prolog, primes

```
prime_factors(N, [_:_]) :- prime_factors(N, [_:_], 2).

prime_factors(N, [_:_], D) :- N mod D == 0,  N1 is N div D, 
                          prime_factors(N1, [_:D], D).

prime_factors(N, [_:_], D) :- N mod D =\= 0, D1 is D+1, prime_factors(N, [_:_], D1).
```

This is my proposed solution to find the prime factors of an input N.

When I try to run it I am getting an error about such a predicate/2 not existing - is my syntax somehow wrong with the extended predicate/3?

Comment: What is `[_:_]` doing here?

Comment: I think perhaps it may not be allowed, but for me it made sense as being equivalent to a list that is empty or not empty but the contents aren't being used as each time I'm just appending D to the end

Comment: but an empty list is `[]`, and a "cons" has syntax `[..|..]`, *not* `[..:..]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a second parameter that only seems to unify in the second case, does not seem to make much sense. Furthermore this is *not* the way you construct a list in Prolog anyway, since:

1. the "cons" has syntax `[H|T]`, so then it should be `[_|_]`;
2. by using underscores the predicates are not interested in the values, you each time pass other parameters; and
3. in Prolog one typically does not construct lists with answers, typically backtracking is used. One can use `findall/3` to later construct a list. This is usually better since that means that we can also query like `prime_factor(1425, 3)` to check if `3` is a prime factor of `1425`.

We can thus construct a predicate that looks like:

```
prime_factor(N, D) :-
    find_prime_factor(N, 2, D).

find_prime_factor(N, D, D) :-
    0 is N mod D.
find_prime_factor(N, D, R) :-
    D < N,
    (0 is N mod D
    -> (N1 is N/D, find_prime_factor(N1, D, R))
    ;  (D1 is D + 1, find_prime_factor(N, D1, R))
    ).
```

For example:

```
?- prime_factor(1425, R).
R = 3 ;
R = 5 ;
R = 5 ;
R = 19 ;
false.

?- prime_factor(1724, R).
R = 2 ;
R = 2 ;
R = 431 ;
false.
```

If we want a list of all prime factors, we can use `findall/3` for that:

```
prime_factors(N, L) :-
    findall(D, prime_factor(N, D), L).
```

For example:

```
?- prime_factors(1425, R).
R = [3, 5, 5, 19].

?- prime_factors(1724, R).
R = [2, 2, 431].

?- prime_factors(14, R).
R = [2, 7].

?- prime_factors(13, R).
R = [13].
```

Comment: Are the parentheses in the if-then-else necessary? As in, `(Cond -> (Then) ; (Else))`? I have never used them for a simple conjunction, but now that I see your answer I started wondering if there are cases when without them you get no errors and different results?

Comment: @User9213: no, the brackets are not necessary in a simple case, but here the `Then` and `Else` both have two predicate calls.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This was exactly my question. `,` has higher precedence than `->` and `;`, so the parentheses seem unnecessary.  I couldn't come up with operators that you can use between `->` and `;` that have lower precedence. Unless you have a nested if-then-else, they seem unnecessary, but I assume I am forgetting something.

Comment: @User9213: you are correct that the brackets here are not necessary, but I think it is better to write these anyway, since it could create some confusion. But you are correct that if for example one queries `listing.` then the brackets are gone (but on the other hand, it uses indentation to make it clear how Prolog "groups" expressions).

Comment: Alright, I see. I always get a bit thrown off if I see stuff in code that doesn't seem to have a purpose. I start looking for the reason why it's there.